# Как добавить куки после загрузки страницы в Вордпрессе

Tags: php, wordpress

Вообще возможно как-то добавить куки после загрузки всей страницы, как результат определенной активности на сайте. Например нажатии на кнопку?

```
$info = 1;
setcookie('cookie', serialize($info), time()+3600);
```

Answer (score 0):

Куки в php добавить нельзя, если хоть какая-то информация была выведена на страницу. Это ограничение http протокола. Посмотрите документацию php про setcookie.

После нажатия на кнопку куки можно добавить с помощью js (так все и делают).